# Sql subquery that converts a column into a list

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to write a subquery that will return the result in a string.

Code:

```
SELECT service_provider.service_provider_id,f_name,l_name,email,phone,service_provider.timestamp,categories.category 
FROM service_provider 
INNER JOIN service ON
   service.service_provider_id = service_provider.service_provider_id
INNER JOIN categories ON
   categories.category_id = service.category_id
where service_provider.status = 'active'
```

I have tried above query it return results in separate lines, what I want is when the value in category column is different it should add up in column as a list.

[image: database result]

Comment: Are you looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work properly, when using group concat in a subquery it is returning multiple lines and SQL is throwing an error

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: You should join with the subquery, not put it in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Or you need to make it a correlated subquery so it only returns one row.

Comment: SELECT service_provider.service_provider_id,f_name,l_name,email,phone,service_provider.timestamp,
(select group_concat(category_id) from service
group by service_provider_id)
                     FROM service_provider 
                     left JOIN service ON
                     service.service_provider_id = service_provider.service_provider_id
                     left JOIN categories ON
                     categories.category_id = service.category_id
                     where service_provider.status = 'active'    ( i tried this but subquery returned multiple lines)

Comment: i am new to sql

Comment: Like I said, you need to make it a correlated subquery.

Comment: `(select group_concat(category_id) from service WhERE service_provider_id = service_provider.service_provider_id)`

Comment: it worked but i am still getting duplicate records.

Comment: You don't need to join with `service` any more.

Comment: thanks! it worked too, but can i get the name of categories, currently I am getting ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concatenate all the category names.

```
SELECT service_provider.service_provider_id,f_name,l_name,email,phone,service_provider.timestamp,GROUP_CONCAT(c.category) AS categories
FROM service_provider 
INNER JOIN service ON
   service.service_provider_id = service_provider.service_provider_id
INNER JOIN categories ON
   categories.category_id = service.category_id
where service_provider.status = 'active'
GROUP BY service_provider.service_provider_id
```